# Flex lexical analyzer: remember starting position

Tags: c, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I'm working on a flex program and i want to do the following :

-read a line , split it in tokens, remember the tokens(let's say in array1) 
  if number of tokens equal the number of tokens on the next line(which were remembered in array2) , print array1[i] : array2[i];

First i thought to remember each of the tokens in a matrix , but it's too muahc to do , allocating dynamic memory and so on . I'm sure there is a simple way , i just don't have enough experience with flex.
Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no built-in functionality in Flex to store a sequence of tokens, so that you can print them later. So just do it in normal code.

Comment: Normal code means C matrix and allocations ?

Comment: Yes, normal C code. Just use two (possibly malloced) arrays.

Comment: You could try implementing a simple vector structure yourself and use this. Then let flex return a special value on newline. Just check for this value and you know you're done.

Comment: Ok . Thank you. Can you post it as an answer so I can mark it as a solution ?

Comment: This would be trivial in C++ using a standard vector. If you find dynamic allocation in C too much work, you might want to consider using a language which makes it easier. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no built-in functionality in Flex to store a sequence of tokens, so that you can print them later. So just do it in normal code. Just use two (possibly malloced) arrays. – Thomas Padron-McCarthy

You could try implementing a simple vector structure yourself and use this. Then let flex return a special value on newline. Just check for this value and you know you're done. – Shadowwolf